# Can't create ASP.NET MVC* project on Visual Studio 2012

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2012

I've just downloaded and installed VS2012 Ultimate RC. When I create a new ASP.NET MVC project it refuses to create it with the following error message:
    "The Project File '......' cannot be opened. There is a missing project subtype. Subtype : '{E53F8FEA-EAE0-44A6-8774-FFD645390401}' is unsupported by this installation."

thanks for help.

Comment: Have you tried repairing / reinstalling? Did you upgrade from VS11 beta or previous version?

Comment: Yeah I'm not having any problem, sounds like a corrupted install

Comment: It's the first time I install VS2012 and I haven't upgraded from VS11 beta

Comment: I have it working with no problems....Visual Studio 11

Comment: I'm sure it's a problem of VS not MVC. I'll try a repair and see if it will work.

Comment: I'm having the same problem, non of the suggestions I've found work.  I did have a hell of a time installing VS2012 though. Only installer that worked was the SP1 update.  Seems to run fine.  Any idea's?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alright, it works now. Seems there was a problem in my vs12 installation. A repair has fixed the problem and it's working great now. Thank you guys.

Comment: My projects are working now, but I still have another problem concerning intellisense. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10992983/intellisense-and-code-suggestion-not-working-in-vs2012-ultimate-rc