# Intellisense and code suggestion not working in Visual Studio 2012 Ultimate RC

Tags: intellisense, visual-studio-2012, logfile

I have just downloaded and installed Visual Studio 2012 Ultimate RC, but I'm having an issue with the intellisense: it does not work until I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>. Code suggestions are disabled also (method parameters for example).

I think the problem is with the VS installation, because at the end of the process the following message is shown: "**The event log file is full**".

Why do I have this problem, and what can I do to fix it?

Comment: I've had the same problem. I think this is becouse I've had vs2010 with resharper, and vs2012 imported settings from it. You can make everething to work as expected by Tools->Import and export settins->Reset all settings

Comment: I have resharper installed too, but it seems it's not the problem in my case. in the end, it seems VS12 doesn't activate intellisense by default (you need to use CTRL+Space to get autocomplete and code suggestions). I had to enable it from the Tools->Options configuration menu.

Comment: WHERE in the Tools->Options configuration menu?  Can you please post the complete path?

Comment: it's Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> C# -> Intellisense. check "Show Completion list after a character is typed" and the underlying checkboxes

Comment: Its broken I think... it is not working with Express Web 2012 either

Comment: this doesn't seem limited to the RC version, i had the same issue with the RTM version

Comment: I get the same issue with VS 2012 premium, and nothing work

Comment: Found it under `TOOLS` -> `Settings` -> `Import and Export Settings...`. Doing a reset brought Intellisense back for me.

Comment: Confirmed... Resetting the settings in "Import and Export Settings..." worked.

Comment: Resetting settings did not work for me, only restarting VS2012

Comment: Tools>Options>Text Editor> I would suggest using All Languages here, instead of just a single language like C#, because you will encounter the same frustration again if you forget to set it for the other languages you use.  Hamzad_cne's answer above is correct and will avoid resetting all of your other settings.

Comment: I'm using F# and intellisense pops up then dissapears after half a second making it unusable. Resetting the settings doesn't help

Comment: I just restarted VS2012 and Intellisense worked again

Comment: user1831021's answer below works without having to lose all of your settings just to re-enable one thing.

Comment: can someone explain to me why "Display Line Numbers" is not a default setting after I reset.. *sigh*

Comment: I have been having this problem, but sometimes (not all the time) it is my own foolishness, for trying to get Intellisense to work on a value that is not accessible. Double check the Intellisense behaviour on other known values to make sure that you are having a true problem before trying more drastic solutions.

Comment: When I try that, I get this: Error 1:  Task List Display Settings: The tasklist format has changed.

Which led me to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28189563/the-tasklist-format-has-changed-error-while-reseting-all-settings-in-visual-stud

ie. Just have to make sure you don't have a project open. If you do and got that error, restart and try again.

Answer (score 186):

Go to

`Tools->Options->Text Editor->C# (or All Languages)->General`

and enable `Auto List Members` and `Parameter Information` in right hand side pane.

Comment: I followed these steps, and no dice. the Auto list members is checked, but I am still not getting any intellisense. what's up?

Comment: This is fairly common when you're on a trial version of resharper and the trial runs out. I assume R# turns these settings off and replaces it with the R# version, so when R# goes away, so does any kind of code completion.

Comment: I had this happen with R# and the trial version. Make sure you go through and reenable it for *each type individually*, along with 'All Languages'.

Comment: This worked for me after disabling and re-enabling for All Languages. I had also installed the Resharper trial and had it expire.

Comment: best option restart visual studio

Comment: Tried alot closing and opening the visual studio..this one works good for me...thanks

Answer (score 118):

Restarting VS2012 should fix the problem.

Comment: Came her to answer this! Nothing else worked, but hey! This is windows! Just restart VS! (I would go for a rebbot next if it didn't work).

Comment: I wish there was a better solution to this problem, but this is the only thing that seems to work.  There seems to be no reason that the intellisense stops working and it seems to happen at the most inconvenient times for me.  Would love an update if someone finds a permanent fix.

Comment: worked for me four! My Intellisense stopped working as I was writing some very simple textbook C# code and a restart fixed it. Not sure why...

Comment: I just reopen the file I am using. No need to restart whole vs.

Comment: Sometimes it really is that simple... I thought I accidentally had pressed a hot key to disable it or something. Worked in VS2013.

Comment: the default solution for all microsoft's product installed in microsoft's OS

Comment: Bill Gates gates just called from the 90's. He wants his answer back! (this answer worked for me!).

Comment: Worked for me. Thanks.

Comment: hah, hah!  :-)  Yes, this also helped me with some weird failures...  Intellisense seemed to be deliberately hiding all but primitive types.  I did happen to just change some class and file names.....  not sure if that was part of it.  But just close all and restart seems to help :-D

Answer (score 27):

Look at this post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8902232/how-to-turn-intellisense-on-in-visual-studio-2010).

This worked for me:

Delete the files in this folder. vs2010:

```
 %AppData%\Microsoft\VisualStudio\10.0\ReflectedSchemas
```

vs2012;

```
%AppData%\Microsoft\VisualStudio\11.0\ReflectedSchemas
```

**VS Ultimate 2013;**

```
%AppData%\Microsoft\VisualStudio\12.0\ReflectedSchemas
```

**VS Professional 2015;**

```
%AppData%\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0\ReflectedSchemas
```

Comment: This was the only fix that worked for me! Thanks so much! Its 12.0 now

Comment: The only fix that help me. Thanks.

Comment: To me, the correct path was "%AppData%\Microsoft\VisualStudio\12.0\ReflectedSchemas" since %AppData% included Roaming

Comment: Worked! You might need a restart

Comment: \Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0 for Visual Studio 2015

Answer (score 26):

Another possible solution is to completely reset the settings. This is what fixed it for me:

`Tools->Import and Export settings->Reset all settings.`

Comment: Worked perfectly for me.  I'd only lost some intellisense (eg argument signatures for VB methods).  Didn't like the idea of deleting files in some folder when I didn't know what it did.

Comment: Worked great for me. I had to restart the IDE after the reset to get it working.

Comment: When I try that, I get this: Error 1:  Task List Display Settings: The tasklist format has changed.

Which led me to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28189563/the-tasklist-format-has-changed-error-while-reseting-all-settings-in-visual-stud

ie. Just have to make sure you don't have a project open. If you do and got that error, restart and try again.

Answer (score 19):

A. Save or export out your Import/Export settings:

**Tools->Import and Export settings**

B. Do the Import/ Export reset:

**Tools->Import and Export settings->Reset all settings.**

C. Go back and reload your original settings again! Intellisense works and you have your original settings back!

Comment: Worked for me on VS 2012 (though I also had to completely exit VS and start it up again for the changes to take effect). Thanks!

Answer (score 14):

I use this to solve it, go to cmd line

```
devenv.exe /setup /resetuserdata /resetsettings
```

Comment: this one is worked for VS 2013. There is no problem for now :)

Comment: Alas, this didn't help for me. Now at startup I get a lot of error messages (compatibilitychecker not found, something with PHP, etc). Messages I didn't get before. Besides it didn't help: intellisense still works, but after event += I still don't get the tab character for autocomplete that ought to fill in the code for the event handler

Comment: This is not safe. My VS now has error and would not run anymore, needs repair/reinstallation. Use the Reset All Settings instead from Tools

Answer (score 4):

The basic idea here is to force a resync of the database Intellisense is using.

If the reference is to a project within your solution. Remove the project. Then add the reference using browse option from the exact path of the project you just removed. Do a quick build and check to ensure reference is picked up correctly. Now add the old project back to the solution and remove the old reference and add it as part of the solution.

This idea of forcing the resync of the database could also be done in other ways too. For example by using an absolute folder path.

Comment: Thanks! Was jumping around header files all day because intellisense wasn't working in a single file which had no errors!

Answer (score 4):

[image]

1. Go to tools->options.
2. Make sure the above check boxes are checked.

Answer (score 2):

Resharper->Options->IntelliSense->General 
Set to 'Visual Studio native IntelliSense...'

Answer (score 1):

It got frustrating for me as well but I figured out my own answer.  Restarting did help but I found why I ran into trouble: I'd copied and pasted an ASP Panel with controls I'd need to re-use.  I only had those in the first Div tag working.  All others needed to be set up, so I said "Aha ... let me comment out the remaining Div Tags that aren't set up ..." and sure enough, intellisense came right back on.

So not only will it fail to work if the cursor is below a code error but it can fail to work if you're a copy / paste type like me.

Answer (score 1):

My solution (VS 2013) was to run as an administrator

Answer (score 1):

Its very Simple,

1. Close visual studio (Having Solution)(Remember Configuration and Solution type and start up project)
2. Go to solution path
3. Delete SolutionName.suo
4. Open Solution again
5. set Configuration and Solution type and start up project (if it is changed)
6. Build and check

Reason why it happend
In my case i have changed the references of some project

Answer (score 1):

My quick solution was to close all opened files in text editor area and then reopen them again from Solution Explorer.

Answer (score 0):

None of the solutions worked for me. I noticed that the problem was only occuring in one xaml file, and not in other xaml or c# files.

I had an extension called QuickConverter that allows to create custom bindings with in-line converters. This was messing up with Intellisense and this was not detected as an error while building or running the app.

My advice is:

- Check if Intellisense stops working in all files or just a particular one
- If it's just one file, look for red or blue squiggly lines and you will find the culprit

Answer (score 0):

I occasionally encountered the same problem as the OP.

Unfortunately, none of the above solutions works for me. -- I also searched from internet for other possible solutions, including Microsoft's VS/windows forum, and did not find an answer.

But when I closed the VS solution, there was a message asking me to download and install "[Microsoft SQL Server Compact 4.0](http://www.microsoft.com/en-US/download/details.aspx?id=17876)"; per this hint I finally fixed the problem.

I hope this finding is of any help to others who may get the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to disable the resharper, or spell checker extension and restart. 
Granted this is not ideal.

Answer (score 0):

In my case `.csproj` file got corrupted and Visual Studio excluded some class files from the solution (But they were still visible in Visual Studio so the issue wasn't obvious at first sight). In these files intellisense was not available. So the fix was to add the files back to the solution.

Answer (score 0):

I had been facing this problems since 2 weeks, finally figured it out using a Sysinternal tool called Process monitor (ProcMon.exe). The problem has to do with the automatic updates settings. I applied the below solution and got it working

Solution: Tools -> Options -> Environment -> Extensions and Updates -> (uncheck) Automatically check for updates->OK

Answer (score 0):

Sometime your code syntax has error, like you use " in ", it must be " ...'...."
For help you quickly detect problems, you click **Design button**, vs try to render, and it will show the line of error

Answer (score 0):

I've just had this happen to me - and (while it was not instantly obvious) it was due to Resharper (R#) being disabled during a licensing issue.

Enabling Resharper fixed this for me!

Answer (score 0):

Generally I face the same problem when I copy some snippets from internet with some special chars that breaks the Intellisense.

It happened a few times with me, I discovered the problem after deleting the file and creating a new one, now when I face the same problem, fist I restart the Visual Studio, if this doesn't resolve the problem, I remove the last snippet I copied from internet and do it by hand, them the problem is gone.