# Intellisense and error highlighting not working by default in VS2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012, intellisense

I've recently bought a new computer and as such have had to install visual studio 2012 onto it. When I installed it onto my last computer, everything worked fine by default; this time, auto-completion is off/not working and neither is error highlighting.

I've tried resetting the settings to their [defaults](http://blog.jongallant.com/2012/07/intellisense-visual-studio-2012.html) but this has had no effect.

What else can I try?

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Intellisense and code suggestion not working in VS2012 Ultimate RC](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10992983/intellisense-and-code-suggestion-not-working-in-vs2012-ultimate-rc)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you try the second suggestion here [Intellisense and code suggestion not working in Visual Studio 2012 Ultimate RC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10992983/intellisense-and-code-suggestion-not-working-in-vs2012-ultimate-rc)

Delete the files in this folder:

%AppData%\Roaming\Microsoft\VisualStudio\11.0\ReflectedSchemas

Answer (score 3):

Select Tool -> Options, then Text Editor. Under the language you are using (ie C#), go to the Advanced and make sure the Underline errors in the editor and Show live semantic errors are checked