# Wrong behavior of the compiler in Visual Studio 2012 after opening project create in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012

I read that there is no problem to use `Visual Studio 2012` for projects written of `Visual Studio 2010`. I open my project in vs 2012 and start it, everything was working. I can make changes in the existing classes and pages, no problems occur. After that I decide to add new class and here nothing was working correctly:

1. References to the other classes, if I add `DataSet` and add using `System.Data` it is not shown like special word(in green)
2. No errors no warning about new classes shown by the compiler. If I write 12312312 and build no error is shown.

Errors are shown in the browser, but I strongly prefer to have a working compiler.

Do you know what is the problem and how to fix it ?

Comment: @Ethan I tried clean and rebuild nothing happen and build was succeed even with the errors in the new class. I will try to do every step in your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cleaning and Rebuilding is the way to start.

For more detailed info, take a look at this post:

[Visual Studio 2012 - Intellisense sometimes disappearing / broken](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13375961/visual-studio-2012-intellisense-sometimes-disappearing-broken)

For the Compiler not showing errors, give this a shot:

Delete the files in this folder:

%AppData%\Roaming\Microsoft\VisualStudio\11.0\ReflectedSchemas

Pulled from [Intellisense and error highlighting not working by default in VS2012](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13783969/intellisense-and-error-highlighting-not-working-by-default-in-vs2012)

Comment: ok I fixed the  Intellisense but what with the compiler return build succeeded when they are errors.

Comment: Thanks man the other problem was that the new class build action was Content not Compile

Comment: Good deal. Have a great day.