# Visual Studio 2012 Ultimate IntelliSense doesn't work well when code has error

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, intellisense

I use visual studio 2012 update 1. When I compiled my code I have an error and on this error IntelliSense doesn't work any way. I used **<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SPACE</kbd>** but nothing shown. I thought I should use it from menu but either nothing shown again.

What's a problem? Is it about visual studio? How can I fix it?

Comment: Could you give us some context? An example?

Comment: I faced this in XAML in VS2010.

Comment: I change one of my input parameters name and after this I compiled it before rename in method body. After this change intellisense didn't work, and when I renamed variables and correct errors, it worked well.

Comment: I have some other problems, too. For instance in another project that is WCF project after one or two debug it (I mean VS) doesn't work well, and must reopen it for continuing development.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Tools -> Options-> Text Editor-> C# or All Languages -> General` and then check/enable `Auto List Members and Parameter Information`

[image]

If that isn't work Delete the files under the this folder:

```
%AppData%\Roaming\Microsoft\VisualStudio\11.0\ReflectedSchemas
```

If that isn't work also, I thins you have no chioce. Start to think reset your settings following first `TOOLS -> Settings -> Import and Export Settings` for saving old settings.

Check out also;

- [Intellisense and code suggestion not working in Visual Studio 2012 Ultimate RC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10992983/intellisense-and-code-suggestion-not-working-in-vs2012-ultimate-rc)

Comment: It had this settings on that situation/time.

Comment: That's good Idea to delete Roaming files. But what are the affects of these files?

Comment: I saw that post before, Thanks.

Comment: Resharper disabled "Auto list members" and "Parameter information". That's why, after suspend or uninstall , the checkboxes have to checked again.

Answer (score 2):

This is what fixed it for me:

```
Tools->Import and Export settings->Reset all settings.
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try to [reset](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms241273%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) your IDE Settings.

I can confirm that it seems not be a bug in Visual Studio 2012. Mine works as expected.

Comment: I don't want to do this. As you know it kills times.

Comment: @Ahmad: Sorry for my ignorance, what do you mean "kills times"? I for one do not know.

Comment: @amalgamate This is not what I want. restarting visual studio and loading projects take long time.