# Razor and Intellisense in VS2012 unresolved

Tags: c#, visual-studio, razor, ide, intellisense

```
@if (Request.IsAuthenticated && User.IsInRole("Administrators")
{
     <div id="sidebar">
        <div class="module">
        <ul class="menu">
                            <li>@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")</li>
                            <li>@Html.ActionLink("About", "About", "Home")</li>
                            <li>@Html.ActionLink("Contact", "Contact", "Home")</li>
                        </ul>
         </div>
         <div class="mainContent">
             Hello, @User.Identity.Name !
         </div>
     </div>
}
```

In this code, when I type in `@User.`
 then I don't see any list of methods or properties avaliable in `User` class for me to autocomplete the call. Could someone guide me steps to fix this issue ?

Comment: try referring to this problem in here

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10992983/intellisense-and-code-suggestion-not-working-in-vs2012-ultimate-rc

Comment: @Chief Thank you, but in my case it doesn't work with Razor, code suggestion works with everything except Razor

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you're missing a `)` after `@if (Request.IsAuthenticated && User.IsInRole("Administrators")`

Comment: If you didn't have intellisense trouble with <code>User</code in the <code>@if</code> test then you shouldn't have trouble elsewhere. Then I'd guess you have a syntax error after the test on the page.

Comment: I have intellisense problem in all of cs razor files not just this piece of code, there is no autocomplete popup of methos and properties for me