# VS 2012 Intellisense and Class highlighting not fully working with old ASP.NET website project

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012, intellisense, webforms

My intellisense and class highlighting does not work on one of ASP.NET website projects.  *It works for all other projects, including other ASP.NET website projects* but just not this one.

The project was written in VS2010 and I've inherited it but am finding it difficult to use without code highlighting and auto-complete!

**Note: my general VS2012 settings seem correct as I've never experience this with other projects loaded.  I even created a new ASP.NET website project to check this, and yep, it all works fine in the new project!**

If I type the first letter of a word that should be recognised e.g. the "`S`" of `System` then hitting `ctrl-space` gives me a list of options for logic operators, local variables, types such as:

`for`

`myLocalVar`

`string`

but no options for classes - so `System` doesn't appear, neither do any of my classes.  If I do type out a class name in full then it will stay black and not be highlighted.

Here are two screen shots of the intellisense not working and the lack of highlighting.  Any suggestions much appreciated!

[image: intellisense-fail]

[image: code-highlight-fail]

Comment: I have the exact same problem.

Comment: I think my issue was deeper than just VS settings/preferences. It turns out that the project I was using was an attempt (a failed one) to convert a WebForms project into an MVC application.  Sorry I can't be more specific, but if I come up with anything I'll post it here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was actually an **issue with my .suo file**.  This is the file that stores some user settings etc.

I deleted this file, and then re-saved the solution (**.sln file**).

Next time I opened the site I opened it using the .sln file instead of opening it as a web site:

> File->Open->Project/Solution **instead of** File->Open->Web Site.

Hope this helps someone in the future.

Answer (score 0):

A few questions, do you have ReSharper or any other development productivity tool that could have changed the settings for this particular project?

If not, then have you checked out the suggestions in this SO question?

[Intellisense and code suggestion not working in Visual Studio 2012 Ultimate RC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10992983/intellisense-and-code-suggestion-not-working-in-vs2012-ultimate-rc)

Comment: Yeah I tried this and no luck. It's literally only this one project which doesn't give me any Intellisense love.  It must be something to do with it being a really old Website/webforms project...