# Visual Studio- autocomplete not working

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I am writing a program in Microsoft Visual Studio using C++. Recently, I noticed that the auto complete functionality that it provides has stopped working (I think it's called intellisense or something?) So now, when I'm typing code, if I write something like: `className.` previously, once I had typed the `.` a little dialogue box would appear listing the functions and variables that were available in that class, but now this no longer happens, and Visual Studio no longer automcompletes the names of the variables that I'm typing...

Anyone know why this is? How can I get this automcompete feature working again? I've tried going to Tools --> Options --> Text Editor --> C/C++ and in the 'Statement Completion' section, the 'Auto list members' and 'Parameter information' checkboxes are both checked...

Comment: Look in build folder for .sdf file and delete it when VS is closed.

Comment: Which is the build folder?

Comment: Search the folder where your project is for it.

Comment: Thans for the suggestion- it was actually a .ncb file that I needed to delete.

Comment: My case was almost similar. Autocomplete popped up on top left corner of IDE instead of cursor mouse. I didn't see an .ncb file, I deleted .sln file to resolve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix this, I needed to delete the .ncb file from the project folder when Visual Studio was closed.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried going to Tools->Import and export settings->Reset all settings

Comment: This could also happen if your intelliSense is buggered. However, do what @vivrichards said and also restart your visual studio to be sure.

Comment: I don't kno if it makes a difference... but I am opening Visual Studio using a batch fie. However, I have always used this batch file to open it, and was using it when intelliSense was previously working...

Comment: Have you looked at this thread [visual studio intellisense problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10992983/intellisense-and-code-suggestion-not-working-in-vs2012-ultimate-rc)

Answer (score 0):

**tldr: Try ctrl+alt+space and make sure you opened the .sln, not just a file or folder**

Old question but I ended up here with this problem so I'm sure someone else eventually will too:

Adding to the other valid answers, this could be due to intellisense going into low impact mode, from accidentally hitting ctrl+alt+space(default). This deactivates autocompletes on many contexts, but not all (you should still be able to call functions directly from the current file if that is the source of your problem, but autocomplete after a period is disabled.

ex.: thisFunction() would autocomplete, but not myObject.thatMethod(), nor myObject.someAttribute. Ctrl+alt+space toggles that mode on and off, which can be removed in your keybinds since it's useless for most people.

Lastly, if you opened the folder containing the projet, and not the .snl, you're not going to get full autocomplete across the whole projet. You can tell by looking at your solution explorer, if you're stuck in folder view and not the fully detailed solution tree view