# MS Visual Studio 2019 C# intellisense suggestions not showing up, but autocomplete when pressing tab is working

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

You know how you get suggestions when typing keyowrds,variable names and functions? I dont get any of them. Like absolutely none of them are showing up. I need to look up the functions, parameters and arguments on the documentation before i can program anything.

I have tried multiple solutions to fix this issue including reinstalling visual studio, enabling options in the Text Editor section of the Options menu.

i have tried many of the suggestions here [Visual Studio- autocomplete not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26778323/visual-studio-autocomplete-not-working?rq=1) and here [Intellisense and code suggestion not working in Visual Studio 2012 Ultimate RC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10992983/intellisense-and-code-suggestion-not-working-in-visual-studio-2012-ultimate-rc)

deleting files in the .vs folder and reopening the project seems to make intellisense work only a few times, then it stops working again. I have to keep on deleting .vs files and try again.

happy to provide more information.. any suggestions welcome

Comment: can you describe your problem in more detail? What intellisense you want to see? It will better for you to provide the picture to describe your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Completely uninstalling VS 2019 along with all extensions/addons, deleting any remaining files, then reinstalling seems to have solved the problem for the time being..

for the record, this was my 4th attempt at a reinstall.. not sure why it worked now and not before