# The tasklist format has changed error while reseting all settings in visual studio 2013

Tags: visual-studio-2013

The tasklist format has changed error coming while resetting general setting  in visual studio 2013. following is actual error.

```
Your settings were reset, but there were some errors.
Error 1:  Task List Display Settings: The tasklist format has changed.
```

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer here.  Restart VS2013 and do the Import/Export without a project open.  This worked for me.

https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/868388/task-list-display-settings-the-tasklist-format-has-changed