# IntelliSense don't work - LinQ - Visual studio 2012

Tags: c#, linq, visual-studio-2012, intellisense

I have a problem with IntelliSense, it never work on my computer. I have already search on the web and try some manipulations :
I already check in tools-options-text editor and yes IntelliSense is activated.
I reinstalled visual studio 2012 too but it still don't work.
I add "System.Data.Linq" and "System.Data.Entity" too.
Visual studio suggest me : "caption/tfoot/tbody/..." may be I need to change because I don't want HTML suggest but SQL suggest.
I am on Windows seven professional, working with visual studio 2012 and Microsoft SQL Server 2014. Everything is working between Miscrosft SQL server and Visual studio, I just don't have IntelliSense...
Thanks you

Comment: possible duplicate of [Intellisense and code suggestion not working in Visual Studio 2012 Ultimate RC](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10992983/intellisense-and-code-suggestion-not-working-in-visual-studio-2012-ultimate-rc)

Comment: As I said I already checked all this post.

Comment: What type of file are you editing?

Comment: It's a cshtml file. I have a screen but I can't post a picture yet. I am using HTML code and javascript.

Comment: are you inside a code block?  My guess is that you are not. https://evolpin.wordpress.com/2011/02/14/razor-code-nuggets-vs-code-blocks/

Comment: Hum no, I am in code block.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A colleague solve my problem. He has just installed ".NET Web Development and Tools Blog" from here : http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/11/18/announcing-release-of-asp-net-and-web-tools-2013-1-for-visual-studio-2012.aspx.

Now the text is formating and colored, everything is working !

Comment: Can someone up this topic, this is a real problem with a solution. Sad it has a -3 points ...

Answer (score 0):

> I don't want HTML suggest but SQL suggest.

It is unclear what you seek exactly in intellisense, but VS intellisense is limited. You may want to look into off the shelf (third party addins) for intellisense to do work in `SQL Server Studio` instead.

Regardless in Visual Studio make sure you have these options in `Options`->`Text Editor`->`SQL Server Tools` to your liking:

[image]
[image]

Comment: Ty to trying to help me. I already check this option, it's activated.
I want to InteliSense propose me the contents of my table. Like when I code : db.Employee I want all the champs of the table Employee like FirstName, LastName, EmployeeId ...
For now InteliSense propose me HTML code like that :
<tr
<colgroup